# Adding div and sort in same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add my div to others and sort in the same based on `data-sort` value.

Example:

```
<div id="divbox">
    <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.10">some content</div>
    <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.05">some content</div>
</div>
```

And how to add another div to `divbox` with value `data-sort="0.7"` and i should be placed between two div's how I can do these.

Comment: Right, and how's that going?

Comment: did you mean that you need to add a div in divbox at some event after the first somediv?

Comment: @ Akshay Khandelwal I know my english sucks, I want do add div to  `divbox` and automaticly sort with other divs based on `data-sort` atrubute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** to append new html contents to an element. For ordering use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method and for reflecting it into the dom append in new order using **[`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)** method.

```js
// get the parent div
$('#divbox')
  // append new div to it
  .append('<div class="somediv" data-sort="0.07">some content</div>')
  // get all children divs
  .children()
  // sort the object collection based on data-sort value
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    // get difference for sorting based on number
    return $(b).data('sort') - $(a).data('sort');
    // append back to parent for updating order
  }).appendTo('#divbox');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divbox">
  <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.10">some content</div>
  <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.05">some content</div>
</div>
```

---

Or you can iterate over children and insert div based on the comparison of the attribute value.

```js
// create jQuery object of append content
var $ele = $('<div class="somediv" data-sort="0.07">some content</div>');
// get sort value of it
var dataVal = +$ele.data('sort');

// iterate over existing divs
$('#divbox .somediv').each(function(i) {
  // get sort value of current element
  var thisVal = +$(this).data('sort');
  // if sort value is greter than the first div then append the element before it
  if (i == 0 && dataVal > thisVal) {
    // append before first element
    $ele.insertBefore(this);
    // break the for loop 
    return false;
    // if the element is last or satisfies the codition for insertion
  } else if ($(this).next().length == 0 || (datVal <= thisVal && thisVal > +$(this).next().data('sort'))) {
    // insert the eleemnt 
    $ele.insertAfter(this);
    // break the loop
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divbox">
  <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.10">some content</div>
  <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.05">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ReasonPlay : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

With pure JS you might do as follows;

```js
var myDiv = document.createElement("div"),
  divList = divbox.querySelectorAll(".somediv"),
     frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
myDiv.className = "somediv";
myDiv.dataset.sort = "0.07";
myDiv.textContent = "new text here 07";

divbox.appendChild([...divList].concat(myDiv)
                               .sort((a,b) => +a.dataset.sort - +b.dataset.sort)
                               .reduce((df,div) => (df.appendChild(div),df),frag));
```

```html
<div id="divbox">
    <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.10">some content 10</div>
    <div class="somediv" data-sort="0.05">some content 05</div>
</div>
```